# About Casting Object

Tags: java, object, casting

Is i thought right?
I explain it in code behide //

I read about it from many web but still confuse. Thank for any help :)

This is all we have.

(
class Test

class Animal

class Mammal extends Animal

class Cat extends Mammal

class Dog extends Mammal

)

```
        public static void main(String args[]){
        Test test = new Test();
        Cat c = new Cat();   // Create object Cat, Now variable c refer to Cat.

        System.out.println(c.type); 
        c.thisIs();
        c.getType();
        test.instanceofAllType(c);
        c.giveMilk(c);
        test.line();

        Animal a = c; //It still refer to Object Cat but compiler see it as Animal.
        System.out.println(a.type);
        a.thisIs();
        a.getType();
        test.instanceofAllType(a);
                     //a.giveMilk(a); Can't use. We don't see method giveMilk() from variable type Animal.
        test.line();

        c = (Cat)a; //Compiler see it as Cat as first because we (cast) it back.
        System.out.println(c.type); 
        c.thisIs();
        c.getType();
        test.instanceofAllType(c);
        c.giveMilk(c); //We can see and use method giveMilk() again.
        test.line();
    }
}
```

This is Output

```
Cat
This is a Cat
Type =Cat
Yes ,I'm Animal!
Yes ,I'm Mammal!
Yes ,I'm Cat!
No ,I'm not a Dog
I'm a cat and i get a milk.
==========================
Animal
This is a Cat
Type =Cat
Yes ,I'm Animal!
Yes ,I'm Mammal!
Yes ,I'm Cat!
No ,I'm not a Dog
==========================
Cat
This is a Cat
Type =Cat
Yes ,I'm Animal!
Yes ,I'm Mammal!
Yes ,I'm Cat!
No ,I'm not a Dog
I'm a cat and i get a milk.
==========================
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is what am i thinking about (Casting) is right or wrong. @Joe C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mostly correct.  However this is a bit wrong:

```
       c = (Cat)a; //Compiler see it as Cat as first because we 
                   //(cast) it back.
```

The compiler doesn't know that `a` refers to a `Cat`.  It knows that it *could* refer to a `Cat`.  The compiler does know that the result of `(Cat) a` will be a `Cat` (or `null`) if and only if the typecast succeeds at runtime.  If the typecast doesn't succeed, then an exception will be thrown (at runtime) and the assignment to `c` won't happen.

In short, the compiler doesn't know exactly what will happen, but it does know that the computation will satisfy Java's type-safety rules.